# Insufficient Permission when trying to create a folder on Google Drive via API(v3)

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to create a folder on my Google Drive via the API. I am using Node, and have created a script that fetches a daily report and would like to  via the API, create a folder and upload those files to it daily.

To setup, I have created a project per the doc's [quick start guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs). My setup looks basically the same as that boilerplate minus the function that reads the files in Drive. However, when trying to upload [using the example given in the docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) I get the error: `Insufficient Permission`.

Going through the permissions in the project's interface, there are a bunch of roles to choose from. Currently I have assigned my project as a Folder Administrator (as well as a couple other roles), which *should* give me permissions yet I am still confronted with this error. Perhaps I need to regenerate my `client_secret.json` file to reflect my updated permissions but how do I do that? I have been googling and poking around the interface for quite some time but see no way to regenerate this file.

The code I am using to create a folder looks like this, pretty close to the boilerplate given in the doc's - just to see it work:

```
const drive = google.drive('v3')    
function createFolder (auth) {
      console.log('auth:', auth)
      const fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'daily-report',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents': ['1P924MEzU_1VoL6OOvWPHSo6vb1u9u0a9'],
      }

      drive.files.create({
        auth: auth,
        resource: fileMetadata,
        fields: 'id'
      }, function (err, file) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.error(err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Folder Id: ', file.id);
        }
      });
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATED ERROR:

```
    Token stored to /Users/sg/.credentials/
auth: OAuth2Client {
  transporter: DefaultTransporter {},
  _certificateCache: null,
  _certificateExpiry: null,
  _clientId: 'clientID093420402349.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  _clientSecret: 'totalsecret',
  _redirectUri: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob',
  _opts: {},
  credentials: 
   { access_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
     refresh_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
     token_type: 'Bearer',
     expiry_date: 1520651774212 } }
(node:76284) [DEP0013] DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
fs.js:106
        throw backtrace;
        ^

Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/sg/.credentials/'
    at rethrow (fs.js:101:21)
    at maybeCallback (fs.js:119:42)
    at Object.fs.writeFile (fs.js:1260:14)
    at storeToken (/Users/sg/R2-DS/src/middleware/aptlist-report-auth.js:104:6)
    at /Users/sg/R2-DS/src/middleware/aptlist-report-auth.js:85:7
    at /Users/sg/R2-DS/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/auth/oauth2client.js:95:13
    at Request._callback (/Users/sg/R2-DS/node_modules/google-auth-library/lib/transporters.js:113:17)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/sg/R2-DS/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your script works. So can you confirm the following points again?

1. About the scope.

   - At Quickstart, the default scope is `var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'];`. But in order to use `drive.files.create`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is required to be added to the scopes.
   - If you modified the scope, please remove the file of `drive-nodejs-quickstart.json`. And run the script. By this, the authorization is run and the added scopes are reflected to the refresh token and access token.
2. About the version of googleapis

   - Recently, it is reported that there are some bugs for googleapis of v27.0.0, v26.0.1 and v25.0.0. So please confirm your version just in case. I use v24.0.0.
3. Whether Drive API was enabled at API console.

   - About this, I think that from your question, you may have already enabled it.

If these were not useful for you, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/drive-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];
var TOKEN_DIR = './';
var TOKEN_PATH = 'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
  // Drive API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), createFolder);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var auth = new googleAuth();
  var oauth2Client = new auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token));
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function createFolder(auth) {
      const drive = google.drive('v3');
      console.log('auth:', auth);
      const fileMetadata = {
        'name': 'daily-report',
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents': ['1P924MEzU_1VoL6OOvWPHSo6vb1u9u0a9'],
      };

      drive.files.create({
        auth: auth,
        resource: fileMetadata,
        fields: 'id',
      }, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
          // Handle error
          console.error(err.message);
        } else {
          console.log('Folder Id: ', file.id);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Yes! thank you!! I had updated the scopes, but did not know i needed to remove the `drive-nodejs-quickstart.json`!!!! Thanks a million :)

Comment: @HolyMoly Thank you for your reply. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Comment: It was but now I have a follow up :( once I got the permissions resolved by removing that bit - I was asked to go to a url and allow the project access, which I did (I had done this before when I first set it up) when I entered the token given to me in at the prompt in terminal I got this error: `DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.
fs.js:113
      throw err;  // Forgot a callback but don't know where? Use NODE_DEBUG=fs
` - the code that attempts to upload _has_ a callback. Do you by chance know what this error is referring?

Comment: @HolyMoly I'm really sorry for the inconvenienve. I have never seen the message. So can I ask you about the version of googleapis? What version are you using for googleapis? If you are using v27.0.0, v26.0.1 and v25.0.0, how about using v24.0.0?

Comment: in NODE_DEBUG mode it says `EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/Users/sg/.credentials/'` - and when I open that file...that `drive-node-quickstart.json` file is in there! should I delete it?

Comment: silly question, but where would I look for that version number?

Comment: @HolyMoly After remove ``drive-node-quickstart.json``, when the script is run, the authorization message is displayed. At this time, please import the code. By this, new ``drive-node-quickstart.json`` is created by reflecting the new scopes.

Comment: yes, i deleted the file and re-ran the code, at which point I was asked to reauthorize, and did.  am getting the same error and unfortunately, the file was not regenerated :(

Comment: @HolyMoly Please try ``$ npm list --depth=0``. If you install googleapis to gloval, please try ``$ npm list --depth=0 -g``. If you are using v27.0.0, v26.0.1 and v25.0.0, please try v24.0.0.

Comment: oh! it's in the package.json! lol! tuh :) I am using v25.0.0 - i will try v24.0.0 ... will I need to make any changes to my code other than the version number?

Comment: going down to 24.0.0 didn't work, but I really do appreciate you getting me past that first bump ;)

Comment: @HolyMoly I'm sorry for the inconvenience. Can you try to do this flow? 1. You authorize it after the file ``drive-nodejs-quickstart.json`` is removed. 2. Run the script. You see ``DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.``. 3. Please run the script again. By this, what message do you see?

Comment: it gives me the error again, and says the token was stored to `/.credentials/` -- the problem is that the file is being recreated, but it's blank - I will update my answer with the exact error if it helps

Comment: @HolyMoly In my environment, I cannot reproduce your situation. I'm sorry. So how about using the working directory instead of $HOME, because I'm not sure about the permission in your environment? If ``drive-nodejs-quickstart.json`` is created by authorizing, I think that your script works because the new scopes are reflected to the access token.

Comment: I am doing all of this out of my projects directory

Comment: @HolyMoly Where is ``client_secret.json``?

Comment: it's at the root of my project's directory

Comment: @HolyMoly I updated my answer. I added the modified quickstart for your situation. Please put ``client_secret.json`` on the current working directory. This modified script creates ``drive-nodejs-quickstart.json`` on the current working directory. Please try this. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: @HolyMoly I confirmed that in my environment, this modified script works at googleapis v24.0.0.

Comment: This worked! I have my folder in Drive! What a relief! hahahah! You are amazing! Thank you soooo much, I have been at this for hours going bonkers, you have been so patient, I really can't thank you enough! :)

Comment: @HolyMoly I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.